# configuring xampp in linux mint 32 bit os

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am trying to install xampp on linux mint 32 bit OS. I downloaded xampp from [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html). And I got a xampp-linux-1.8.3-5-installer.run file. I tried to run that file but its showing me error. Can anyone help me to install xampp in my linux mint.

I am a noob in linux and I'm using it for the first time. I found some linux commands to install xampp. But it didn't help me well.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact error, you will find a guide [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) on how to install Apache, Mysql and PHP on Ubuntu which uses the same install commands as Linux Mint.